# Difference between Sheet.Range.Value and Sheet.Range.Cells

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I'm curious as to what is the difference between Sheet.Range.Value and Sheet.Range.Cells? I know that the former one is getting value from the specified range while the latter one I'm not quite sure. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in the comments of your previous post. But here's the explanation again...

There is no "cell" of Range("F2:G2") or a `value`. `F2:G2` is a Range of cells (or an array if you're thinking in python). Think of a column of cells in excel, if you entered the formula `="F2:G2"` you wouldn't get a value. you must specify if you want to add, average, concatenate, etc.

The `cells` is a collection of all cells in the range. You can loop through them, count them, etc.

Here's an illustration:

```
Sub SubName()
    'put some text into cells A1:A3"

    Dim aCell As Range, helperText As String

    For Each aCell In Range("A1:A3").Cells
        'captures the value of each cell
        helperText = helperText & aCell.Value

        MsgBox "You are looping through the range and on cell " & aCell.Address _
        & ", and the concatenated result of this loop is " & helperText

    Next aCell

End Sub
```